# paypal express checkout in Client-side REST doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, paypal, paypal-sandbox, payment

Iam using paypal express checkout in Client-side REST and i followed this link
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/basic-integration/
and i copy pasted the code in the "full interactive demo"
and changed the client.sandbox value to be my app client id and when i click on the button named "paypal checkout" a popup window appear and asks for email address and password and after enter them and press login it gives me error message "Sorry, we can’t complete your purchase at this time" i don't know why this error and how to solve it. I really appreciate any help please.

Comment: Can you share your code, with the client id? You may also get some idea of what's going wrong by looking at the console logs.

Comment: I solved it, the problem was in the client id of the sand box application was related to a merchant account that is in Egypt country but when i created a merchant account in US country and related it to the application it worked for me. Thanks too much for helping me @bluepnume